# JPassword Field and Username Field (login system) not showing

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtextfield

I know I don't have a frame but everything shows except my `JPasswordField` (password bar) and my `JTextField` (username bar) I'm just trying to add a "username" and "password" bar at the bottom of the page but the bars won't show.

Thanks for the help although it seems as everything here receives negatives. lol.

```
public class test extends JFrame {

private JLabel jl;
private JLabel paypalLogo;
private JButton money1;
private JButton money2;
private JButton money3;
private JButton money4;
private JButton money5;
private JButton money6;
private JButton custom;
private JTextField user;
private JButton login;
private JPasswordField pass;


public test(){
    super("PayPal Money Generator");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    this.setLayout(null);


    Icon logo1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("res/paypal.png"));
    paypalLogo = new JLabel(logo1);
    paypalLogo.setBounds(50,-50,200,200);
    add(paypalLogo);


    money1 = new JButton("$5");
    money1.setBounds(85,100,35,35);
    add(money1);

    money2 = new JButton("$10");
    money2.setBounds(200,100,35,35);
    add(money2);

    money3 = new JButton("$25");
    money3.setBounds(67,200,50,35);
    add(money3);

    money4 = new JButton("$50");
    money4.setBounds(200,200,50,35);
    add(money4);

    money5 = new JButton("$200");
    money5.setBounds(50,300,70,40);
    add(money5);

    money6 = new JButton("$500");
    money6.setBounds(200,300,70,40);
    add(money6);

     user = new JTextField(15);
     add(user);
     pass = new JPasswordField(15);
     add(pass);
     login = new JButton("Login");
     add(login);





    /*how to make logo in button test
    Icon b = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("res/paypal.png"));
  custom = new JButton("", b);
  custom.setBounds(10,10,100,100);
  add(custom);
  */

 HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
 money1.addActionListener(handler);
 money2.addActionListener(handler);
 money3.addActionListener(handler);
 money4.addActionListener(handler);
 money5.addActionListener(handler);
 money6.addActionListener(handler);





}

public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(user.getText().trim().length() == 0 || pass.getText().length() == 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fill");
        }else{
            if(user.getText().equals("Kleo") || user.getText().equals("Kleo")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome");
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Denied");
            }
        }
    }
}



private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          try {
            final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/paypal.png")));
              JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                      null,
                      e.getActionCommand() + ".00 USD has successfully been added to your account!",
                      "",
                      JOptionPane.OK_OPTION,
                      JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                      icon,
                      new Object[]{"OK"},
                      "");
          } catch (IOException exp) {
              exp.printStackTrace();
          }



 }

    }
```

}

Comment: `this.setLayout(null);` isn't a good start

Comment: Yup, you lost me at `this.setLayout(null);`.

Comment: `although it seems as everything here receives negatives` and this is not a good follow-up to the aforementioned bad start.

Answer (score 4):

When you use a null layout, you the programmer are completely responsible for setting all the locations and sizes of components added to the container. You don't set either of these for your JTextField or JPasswordField. The quick (***and wrong***) solution is to set their bounds. The better solution is to use layout managers.

Answer (score 4):

The use of a `null` layout is the main cause of your problem...

```
this.setLayout(null);
//...
user = new JTextField(15);
add(user);
pass = new JPasswordField(15);
add(pass);
login = new JButton("Login");
add(login);
```

Basically when a component is created, it's default size and position are `0x0`, meaning that, based on the above code, you components aren't visible because they have no size.

Swing was designed to work with layout managers and there are many good reasons to use them.  You don't control the rendering process by which content is rendered to the screen, this will effect things like the font metrics, which will change the size that components needs to be and effect the placement of components around each other...

Short answer, use appropriate layout managers

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

You will be hard pushed to find an experienced Swing developer worth their salt who would advocate the use of `null` layouts when dealing with forms of this nature.